# Comparing two time values

Tags: java, string, if-statement, string-comparison

I have participated in a challenge, in which the requirement is to compare two time values `t1` and `t2`, and `print First` if `t1` occurs before `t2` ; otherwise, `print Second`.

And, `t1 != t2`.

**Sample Input:**

```
2
10:19PM 02:49AM
08:49AM 09:10AM
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Second
First
```

**My code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    static String timeCompare(String t1, String t2){
        // Complete this function

        String half1 = t1.substring(t1.length()-2); // gets AM/PM value
        String half2 = t2.substring(t2.length()-2);

        String time1 = t1.substring(0, t1.length()-2);
        String time2 = t2.substring(0, t2.length()-2);

        //System.out.println(time1);

        int hour1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.split(":")[0]);
        int hour2 = Integer.parseInt(time2.split(":")[0]);

        int min1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.split(":")[1]);
        int min2 = Integer.parseInt(time2.split(":")[1]);

        if(hour1 == 12) {
            hour1 = 0;
            //System.out.println(hour1);;
        }
        if(hour2 == 12) {
            hour2 = 0;
        }

        //System.out.println(hour1+" , "+hour2);

        if(half1.equals(half2)){
           // System.out.println(1);

            if(hour1 == hour2){

                if(min1 > min2){
                    return "Second";
                } 
                else{
                    return "First";
                }

            }
            else if(hour1 > hour2){
                return "Second";
            }
            else{
                //System.out.println(2);

                return "First";
            }

        }
        else if (half1 == "AM"){
            return "First";
        }
        else{
            return "Second";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int q = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++){
            String t1 = in.next();
            String t2 = in.next();
            String result = timeCompare(t1, t2);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. But only 1 out of 10 test cases passed.

Can you tell what's wrong?

Comment: Parse it to a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) then simply call [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#compareTo-java.time.LocalTime-).

Comment: `half1 == "AM"` You can't compare Strings like this.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Not that way. I want to do this by if else statements.

Comment: @Nivedita parse to `LocalTime` then use `if(left.compareTo(right) > 0)`. I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @SanketMakani Hey thanks a lot. That fixed everything. Can you post that as an answer so that i can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`half1 == "AM"` Here you have made a mistake. For String comparison , You need to use [String#equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method.

So change that line with `half1.equals("AM")`. This will do your work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to example here:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.of(10, 10, 0)
    LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.of(11, 11, 0);
    int result = t2.compareTo(t1); 
    if(result < 0){
       System.out.println("Second");
    }else if(result > 0 ){
       System.out.println("First");
    }else{
       System.out.println("Same Time");
    }
  }
}
```

The code above generates the following result:

`Second`

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: I don't have to use classes.

Comment: It's not a date - it's a time.